# laravel - save session credentials on login for mobile app

Tags: ios, session, authentication, laravel

I'm new to laravel framework and trying to use it as backend to build an app for iOS. While I'm working on user authentication, I'm trying to store a session credential as a token on mobile device so that user can stay logged in. However laravel doesn't seem to be doing it in this way to remember user's login status. Could anyone please help giving me some suggestions? Thank you for whoever helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figure out how I can get this through.

I create my own customized auth driver function to check if the user possesses a certain auth token, if the user has that token, then log user in.

Based on it, I need to generate a token and store it both on the database & iPhone's keychain. As long as iPhone has this token that matches the one on the database, the user can then stay logged in.

@aBilal17 though I didn't use your solution, but thanks anyway.

Comment: Wow! this is exactly what I need! would you mind editing the answer a bit explaining how you acomplished it? :D thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Use NSUserDefaults for that

```
     [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:txtLogin.text forKey:@"userName"];

     [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:txtPassword.text forKey:@"password"];
```

After that you can get value from NSUserDefaults like this

```
     [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"userName" ]
     [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"password"]
```

Comment: The op wanted to know how to do it with a session / token and not send the credentials on every request. It is much safer and efficient to hide the credentials through a session / token string. That on the other hand is something you could store in the `NSUserDefaults` quite well.